# Validar formualrio sin FormGroup

Tags: angular

Quiero validar un formulario que tiene muchos campos, para la pregunta, usaré solo un campo

```
<form name="scenarioForm" (ngSubmit)="save(scenarioForm)" #scenarioForm="ngForm">
   Scenario label: 
   <input name="scenarioName" min="3" max="50" required type="text" [(ngModel)]="scenario.name" pInputText />
   <p-button type="submit" icon="pi pi-save" label="Save"></p-button>
```

y en mi archivo TypeScript:

```
  save(form: NgForm): void {
      if (form.valid) {
          //Enviamos la información
      } else {

      }
```

Sé que puedo añadir una funcionalidad de deshabilitar el botón de save pero me gustaría además que si le da al botón marque que casilla no es correcta con un recuadro en rojo.

Comment: Para esto te puedes apoyar de las clases ng-invalid, ng-untouched etc. Inspecciona tu input y verás a qué me refiero. Usa css para marcar la casilla en rojo usando esas clases o viceversa.

Comment: viendo ng-invalid solo veo que funciona con formgroup

Comment: logre solucionarlo de esta forma:
<input name="scenarioName" type="text" [(ngModel)]="scenario.scenarioName" pInputText #scenarioName="ngModel" required/>